Misunderstanding a code
I came across a code that I have trouble understanding
Why is there no "command" between (2,0) (end of the 6th line) and (0,0) (beginning of the 7th line)?
Since the line ends without a semicolon, I am surprised that the 7th line does not start with a command
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) to [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,0)
            (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0) -- 
            (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5) -- (0,0)
            (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5);
            \draw [densely dashed, very thin] (0,-0.5) to
            [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


BTW, this is how the long \draw ...; can be decomposed: (0,0) is a move-to path operation, to[...] (2,0) is a to path operation, then the next (0,0) is another move-to operation, followed by a curve-to operation (.. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0)), then a line-to operation (-- (2,-0.5))... . The sec. 14 "Syntax for Path Specifications" of the pgfmanual (unofficial online version) lists them all.

A tikz path does not need to be continuous. You can see this more easily in this simple example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1,-1) -- (1,1) (-1,1) -- (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


(whether or not you then also add a line break between the parts of the path does not really matter)

TL;DR: My response is a bit verbose. If you’re looking for a straightforward answer, please refer to the other reply.
In TikZ, when you're specifying a sequence of path commands, you can chain them together across multiple lines, and the semicolon is only required at the end of the entire path specification. The end of the path is signaled by a semicolon (;), and TikZ will continue interpreting the chain until it encounters this semicolon.
So in your case, the command on line 7 ((0,0)) continues the path started in line 6. TikZ treats this as one continuous path because the semicolon hasn’t been reached yet. Once the path ends (with a semicolon), the drawing of that particular path is completed.
 
In the image, I have highlighted the tips of the lines and curves to clearly show the function of each part of the code. Please note that I had to repeat some coordinates because I explicitly used the \draw command, which requires specifying the starting coordinate.
For example, these lines were continuous and didn't require repeating the starting coordinate because the \draw command was not used in your example:

(2) Blue, (3) green, (4) orange, and (5) purple
(6) Brown, (7) cyan, and (8) magenta


Full code
Image on the left
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, ->, scale=2]
\draw[red] (0,0) .. controls +(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5) .. (2,0); 
      % This draws the top half of a curve from (0,0) to (2,0) with control points above
      
\draw[blue] (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0);
      % This draws the bottom half of the curve from (0,0) to (2,0) using control points below

\draw[green] (2,0) -- (2,-0.5); 
      % This draws a straight line from (2,0) to (2,-0.5), the right upper vertical edge

\draw[orange] (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5); 
      % This draws another curved segment from (2,-0.5) to (0,-0.5), the middle curve

\draw[purple] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0); 
      % A straight line from (0,-0.5) to (0,0), the left upper vertical edge

\draw[brown] (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2); 
      % This draws the right lower vertical edge of the rectangle from (2,-0.5) to (2,-2)

\draw[cyan] (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2); 
      % A curved line from (2,-2) to (0,-2), the bottom curved part of the rectangle

\draw[magenta] (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5); 
      % A straight line from (0,-2) to (0,-0.5), the left lower vertical edge

\draw[densely dashed, very thin, gray] (0,-0.5) to [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,-0.5);
      % A dashed line across the middle, connecting (0,-0.5) to (2,-0.5)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Image on the right
% 'standalone' class used just to visually isolate the problem
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1mm]{standalone}

\DeclareRobustCommand\circled[1]{% <- important, do not remove
    \tikz[baseline = (char.base)]{
        \node[draw, circle, inner sep = 1pt]
            (char) {#1};
    }
}

\tikzset{stepNumber/.style={
    midway,
    fill=white,
    font=\scriptsize,
    inner sep=0pt
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, ->, scale=2]
\draw[red] (0,0) .. controls +(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5) .. (2,0) node[stepNumber] {\circled{1}};
      % 1. This draws the top half of a curve from (0,0) to (2,0) with control points above
      
\draw[blue] (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0) node[stepNumber] {\circled{2}};
      % 2. This draws the bottom half of the curve from (0,0) to (2,0) using control points below

\draw[green] (2,0) -- (2,-0.5) node[stepNumber] {\circled{3}}; 
      % 3. This draws a straight line from (2,0) to (2,-0.5), the right upper vertical edge

\draw[orange] (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5) node[stepNumber] {\circled{4}};
      % 4. This draws another curved segment from (2,-0.5) to (0,-0.5), the middle curve

\draw[purple] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) node[stepNumber] {\circled{5}};
      % 5. A straight line from (0,-0.5) to (0,0), the left upper vertical edge

\draw[brown] (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2) node[stepNumber] {\circled{6}};
      % 6. This draws the right lower vertical edge of the rectangle from (2,-0.5) to (2,-2)

\draw[cyan] (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2) node[stepNumber] {\circled{7}};
      % 7. A curved line from (2,-2) to (0,-2), the bottom curved part of the rectangle

\draw[magenta] (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5) node[stepNumber] {\circled{8}};
      % 8. A straight line from (0,-2) to (0,-0.5), the left lower vertical edge

\draw[densely dashed, very thin, gray] (0,-0.5) .. controls +(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5) .. (2,-0.5) node[stepNumber] {\circled{9}};
      % 9. A dashed line across the middle, connecting (0,-0.5) to (2,-0.5)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Let me try it this way, augmenting the other answers already given. Let's work with a movie as an analogy.
Path concept
Syntactically you start a path with \ and end it with ; . This is in analogy like shouting action! and cut! when taking a movie scene ... everything in between is ... something performed.
That's why you draw e.g. a simple line like this:
    \draw  (0,0) -- (2,0);

Requests to the "actors"
Before finishing the path (scene) you may call other tikz-commands, but WITHOUT \, as the current path still wasn't finished by ; (it's still the same scene, only done a bit different).
Here I put 2 nodes "in between":
    \draw  (0,0) -- node[red]{X} node[pos=0.9,above,teal]{Y} (2,0);

Making a more complicated path  ("scene")
This one is the first, longer part of the 2 draw-statements you posted, with all those fancy controls replaced by its linear version, the -- . To give some orientation I put 3 nodes at the end of the 3 partial lines (see samcarter's remark):
    \draw  (0,0) -- (2,0) node[red] {A}
           (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) node[teal] {B}
           (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2) -- (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5) node {C};

Going 3D-ish
Now, what happened in the code you posted, is replacing the standard -- by Bezier curves, i.e. basically the control statements. Syntactically those start with .. and end at .. . To better see the development, I left the red node A from the previous code:
\draw (0,0) to [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,0) node[red] {A}
            (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0) -- 
            (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5) -- (0,0)
            (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5);

End-point-wise nothing changed ...
General remark
This is a typical development sequence to draw complex objects:

start (very) simple
refine (e.g. by placing more points)
refine even more (e.g. by introducing curves)


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \section{Drawing just a line}
 Just a simple line:
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (0,0) -- (2,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}

 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \section{Adding nodes}
 Adding a red node in the middle, and y teal one, above, at 90 \% of the path:
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (0,0) -- node[red]{X} node[pos=0.9,above,teal]{Y} (2,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}

 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \section{Several lines in one path}
 This one draws 3 "disconnected" lines in one path:
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (0,0) -- (2,0) node[red] {A}
           (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,-0.5) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0,0) node[teal] {B}
           (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2) -- (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5) node {C};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 % ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \section{Same, but with bent lines}
 It's the same path, using different ways to go from linear to curved lines. Red node A is there for reference:
 
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) to [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,0) node[red] {A}
            (0,0) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (2,0) -- 
            (2,-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-0.5) -- (0,0)
            (2,-0.5) -- (2,-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (0,-2) -- (0,-0.5);
%            \draw [densely dashed, very thin] (0,-0.5) to
%            [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (2,-0.5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

